# reading html pages through R

Tags: html, xml, r, http, url

http://www.imdpune.gov.in/research/ndc/rainfall/DRF_STN.htm

Can someone tell me how to read this data using R Language?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have read the R manual: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html

The problem is the title of the chart. I would copy and paste it to Excel, remove the title and then save as .csv